# How can I call a specific pod, in a service, from outside the kube cluster

Tags: kubernetes

For self-healing I want to be able to call a function on a specific pod instance from outside the kube cluster.

So... I have 2 networks, non-kube, and my kube-cluster. My kube-cluster contains one service, myapp and has 8 replicas spread across 4 nodes. If each of these pods was given a VIP 10.1.1.x where x is from 1 to 8, I want to be able to from any app running in non-kube, be able to call any of the API methods exposed in myapp, but forcing a particular replica.

E.g. myapp has one REST GET method,

```
whatismyvip()
```

And from a console app running in non-kube I want to be able to ensure I get the following output, by calling the above method on the right pod.

```
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.6
10.1.1.8
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.5
```

Why would I want to do something like this? Well, generally the errors that are generated in the kube-cluster service are server errors due to bad data / configuration, rather than the system "going down", i.e. 500 errors, and so I want the client to be smart enough to go

"ok, i got an error from 10.1.1.2, i will try 10.1.1.3"

I'd prefer to do this natively in kubernetes (even if it means custom IngressController) rather than sidecar service mesh, Envoys et al.

Answer (score 1):

Create a loadbalanced service that fronts your replicaset of 8 pods. Define a liveness HTTP probe that pings the `whatismyvip()` HTTP endpoint.

The host kubelet will restart the pod if you get any unexpected HTTP status codes.

[define a liveness HTTP request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request)

Otherwise if what you mean by forcing a particular replica is that you wish to direct your request into a specific pod from outside the cluster, then perhaps a custom solution might be better. Each see if 2 X pods on each node might have a clusterIP service fronting them. Then use a loadbalanced service fronting a custom app that proxies your request for a specific replica or set of pods based on your request.

E.g. a URL query string parameter that targets clusterIP service A, B, C, or D.

`https://customrouterapp/whatismyvip?replicaset=B`

Comment: You are correct in your 2nd paragraph - i wish to direct my request into a specific pod from outside the cluster. It is this custom proxying behavior that I don't know how to do (or if it's indeed possible). Your example URL doesn't allow us to specify a particular pod within the replicaset, so i guess i'm after something more like:

https://customrouterapp/whatismyvip?vip=10.1.1.8

=> 
{ 
    "vip": "10.1.1.8"
}

Comment: I was thinking you could have 4 x deployments (each with its own ClusterIP service type in front of it). Then you have another app- you could create this in flask, go, or nodejs for example, that takes a GET request, with querystring param of the deployment number (4 of these options). E.g. `GET url/whatismyvip?deployment=1`, If that fails when your client calls it, the client tries `deployment=2` etc. till it gets a valid response with an IP of the correct deployment service to call based on which one is up/working. Your client then makes its request to that vip of the service in the cluster.